# Countries with Multiple World Regions

Tags: contacts, location

Is it possible to have a country with more than one world region?  I like the functionality of the world region search but I would like for some regions to be smaller (North America vs. South America) but also have them grouped together as in the current world region (America South, Central, North and Caribbean).

One way of getting around this situation is to create a group of contacts in each county and then creating a regional group that includes all of the appropriate country groups.  I'm hoping that there is a different way to accomplish this same task.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also have a look at the area extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/areas)
In the area extension you can define custom areas and automaticly assign them to a contact based on his address data.

For example if you have the area Benelux, which consists of the countries Belgium, Netherlands and Luxemburg. You configure the area Benelux to be applicable when the country of the contact is either Belgium, Netherlands or Luxemburg.

Below a screenshot of the contact card and areas for east coast and washington dc.

[image]

See the extension page for more examples.

Comment: Upon installing the extension and then changing the settings so that 'Collapse this set on initial display' and 'Collapse this set in Advanced Search' are marked with yes, the follow warning of "Custom group 'Areas' already exists in Database' appears.  How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new regions to the `civicrm_worldregion` table, and reassign countries to the new regions with edits to the `civicrm_country` table.

If you'd like two levels of regions, there isn't a great answer.  You can do groups, like you suggested - if you do, I like using smart groups based on latitude/longitude to automatically group folks.

Another option is to use the new feature of "custom fields on any entity" to add a custom field to the Country entity.  However, you'd need to write code to expose that custom field to search.